# No LOC or Bugs picked up by SonarQube runner

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I am using sonar-web-frontend-plugin

I have the following sonar-project.properties file which is located at this path

```
E:\agent2\test\sonar-project.properties

sonar.projectKey=Test
sonar.projectName=Test
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=src/app
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

I have my source code in the following location

```
E:\agent2\test\src\app
```

My runner is located here

```
E:\agent2\test\.sonarqube\bin\sonar-scanner-2.8\bin\
```

and I am running the following in cmd E:\agent2\test>

```
E:\agent2\test\.sonarqube\bin\sonar-scanner-2.8\bin\sonar-runner -Dproject.settings= E:\agent2\test\sonar-project.properties -X
```

It is all running fine but no issues are being reported and no LOC are being picked up in the log it says the following

Calculating CPD for 0 Files

So it does not actually seems to analyse anything, I know there are issues because when i run TSlint locally i get issues found

Comment: Which sonarqube version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis setup looks okay.

It is very likely that you don't have the relevant language plugin installed on your SonarQube instance. Either that, or your code is contained in files with unrecognized extensions.

Each language plugin tells SonarQube scanner "I'm interested in files with these extensions:..."

The fact that the analysis is over "0 Files" indicates that no file extensions were recognized.

Comment: i added the sonar-web-frontend-plugin and restarted sonar service. The ui picks up the rules and lists them as quality gates for css, ts, js etc, if i run tslint in my project that works fine just not through sonar so error cant be in the codebase?

Comment: Not familiar with that plugin. Does it declare the relevant file extensions? Or does it expect you to have installed the plugins that do?

Comment: The log says it Index 171 Files and its picking up the extenstions for example it says "Quality profile for td: tslint" but still it says CPD for 0 files and LOC is zero in the UI